# beforeDraw in Chart JS 3.5.x

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Since I upgraded ChartJS to 3.5, I am unable to adapt the BeforeDraw plugin properly. I've tried searching the internet for an example but I haven't seen anyone providing the beforeDraw update. I put my code below and I would appreciate any guide, help or link to solve the problem.

```
Chart.register({
 
 beforeDraw: function(chart,args,options) {
     
     if(chart.chart.chart.config.type=='doughnut'){
         
         const width = chart.chart.width;
         const height = chart.chart.height;
         const ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
         
         var text;               
         
         ctx.restore();
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 3000, 3000);
         
         fontSize = (height / sizeLabel1).toFixed(2);                                //250
         ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel1;                                                //"#FFFEFE"
         ctx.font = '400 ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
         text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text1; //"CICLE " + currentCicle + "/" + totalCicles; 
         textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
         textY = (height / positionLabel1) ;                                         //3.30                          
         ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
         
         fontSize = (height / sizeLabel2).toFixed(2);                                //90
         ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel2;                                                //"#FFFEFE"
         ctx.font = 'Bold ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
         text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text2; //"1"+"' "+"30"+"''"; 
         textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
         textY = (height / positionLabel2) ;                                         //2.70                                          
         ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
         
         fontSize = (height / sizeLabel3).toFixed(2);                                //150       
         ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel3;                                                //"#FFFEFE"
         ctx.font = '100 ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
         text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text3;
         textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
         textY = (height / positionLabel3) ;                                          //1.90                 
         ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
         
         fontSize = (height / sizeLabel4).toFixed(2);                                //200                   
         ctx.fillStyle = colorLabel4;                                                //"#FFFEFE"
         ctx.font = '400 ' + fontSize * 13 + 'px "Titillium Web"';
         text = chart.config.options.elements.center.text4;
         textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2);
         textY = (height / positionLabel4);                                          //1.50              
         ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);   
         
         ctx.save();
     }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 main things, plugins need an ID. Also you might want to log every line or put breakpoints to see what is going on because afaik the chart does not contain a circulair reference to itself anymore.

So in your first if statement it should just be: `if(chart.config.type === 'doughnut')`.

So basicly your first few lines have to be changed to this:

```js
Chart.register({
 id: 'customText',
 beforeDraw: function(chart,args,options) {
     
     if(chart.config.type=='doughnut')
```

This will probably fix your problem, if not try to log variables you are using and check if you still call them in the correct way.